# Suggestion for model performance improvement for ML competition

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, class-imbalance

I am working on highly imbalanced dataset and trying to increase accuracy(metric: `roc_auc`) of my model which is hovering around 82-83%. This is part of an internal ML competition and people who are at the top have accuracy around 85-88%.

I am just wondering what else I can do to improve my model's accuracy. Any suggestion or tips would be appreciated.

Details of training dataset :

The training data shape is : (166573, 14)

**Distribution of features :**

As you can see, only the first 4 columns go to different max values. 
Rest of the columns have either 1 or 0 value (max: 1, min: 0)

[image]

**Scaling features :**

```
X['scaled_distance']= sc.fit_transform(X['distance'].values.reshape(-1,1))
X['scaled_visit_count'] = sc.fit_transform(X['visit_count'].values.reshape(-1,1))
X['scaled_tier'] = sc.fit_transform(X['tier'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

**Null Handling :**

```
train['tier'].fillna(round(train['tier'].mean(),2),inplace=True)
```

At last, I have tried different models (`Xgboost`, `Random Forest with SMOTE`, `lightbgm` etc..) I have got best results with lightbgm with some tuned parameters..

```
lgbm.fit(X_train,y_train)
LGBMClassifier(bagging_fraction=0.8, bagging_freq=15, boosting_type='gbdt',
        class_weight=None, colsample_bytree=1.0, feature_fraction=0.5,
        importance_type='split', is_unbalance=True, learning_rate=0.01,
        max_depth=7, min_child_samples=20, min_child_weight=0.001,
        min_split_gain=0.0, n_estimators=520, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=40,
        objective=None, random_state=10, reg_alpha=0.0, reg_lambda=0.0,
        silent=True, subsample=1.0, subsample_for_bin=200000,
        subsample_freq=0)
```

Please refer full code here : 
https://github.com/PraveenKS30/ML/blob/master/Surge2019/Surge%20Pre%20Machine%20Learning.ipynb

I am not sure what else I can do to improve my accuracy.. Should I preprocess in different way ? Should I try neural network now?
Please suggest.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to improve accuracy for a _highly imbalanced dataset_? Is that a competition request?

Comment: Yup, it's for the rank on leaderboard.. even if I manage to improve model accuracy by 1%.. I will be in top 10..